# Cannot Break Role Inheritance on Task Items Using REST in SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, office-365, rest

The title pretty much says it all.  I'm getting an 'Unauthorized' response when I try to /breakroleinheritance on a Tasks list item in a 2013 workflow (inside an App Step).  The strange thing is that I can run the command successfully in Fiddler, and I can /breakroleinheritance on items of other list types in 2013 workflows with no problem.  I've tried the command in both an App Step and outside of an App Step, while kicking off the workflow with a site collection admin user - both with the same result.

Client is in O365.  Is this just one of those non-documented oddities about Tasks?  I would be super grateful if someone could try and duplicate this behavior and let me know how they fare.

Thanks!  :-)

Comment: Have you tested if this behavior changes with different arguments combinations?

Comment: I have toggled the copyroleassignments value of true/false.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Does it fail for any combination of copyRoleAssignments and clearSubscopes?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in my env. Could you please check problem statement and the link in accepted answer @ https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/6a6e0694-b66e-47c5-a163-902d5774cf9a/sharepoint-2013-breakroleinheritance-using-rest-api-return-forbidden?forum=sharepointdevelopment? Maybe that helps somehow

Comment: Same results for either true/false.  I tried creating an entirely new workflow, re-enabling the workflow app permissions per this thread:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/58def880-5b07-4d4e-b605-2ab576072bb6/unauthorized-response-for-rest-api-use-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow-office-365?forum=sharepointdevelopment, but still the same behavior.

Are you in O365 and using a Tasks list?

Comment: I've done exactly what you are trying to do with breaking role inheritance on tasks using REST. Just wanted to mention that there is no limitation in this regard. Just not sure exactly why it is not working for you. I'll try to repro this and get back to you, but hopefully this case will be solved by then so that you don't have to wait.

Comment: @Tracy yes, O365, Tasks list, 2013 WF. I wonder if you have another site collection in your tenant to test you workflow? Or maybe post a screenshot of WF...

Comment: You guys are awesome, that's exactly what I need to know!  I  have a test site collection and that is my next move.  I've had a series of odd behaviors in the root site collection of this client's tenant that ultimately led to a Microsoft support ticket, and it's possible this is just another one.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my problems and thought I would note them here in case someone else encounters the same issues.

1. First, a co-worker had overwritten my existing site wide app
   policy for workflows with a list-specific one by changing the scope
   attribute of the AppPermissionRequest and re-trusting it.  It
   appears that rather than appending the policies, they get overwritten. 
   This explains why I could get HTTP calls to work in one workflow
   (that was attached to my co-worker's list), and not my own.
2. Second, when trying to re-create my own site wide app policy for
   workflows I misunderstood [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx) who's picture indicates a
   URL with the app catalog site collection in it rather than the site
   where the workflow lives.  Consequently, I was changing the policy
   in the app catalog site collection and not where it mattered.